# XML Deserialization of DataTable or DataSet

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, serialization, datatable

I have the following XML:

```
     <NewDataSet>
        <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
          <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Data" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Data">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
     </NewDataSet>
```

I know this was created by serializing a DataTable with `new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataTable)).Serialize(writer, (DataTable)myDataTable);`.

The schema as well as the actual data can be different in them.

I need to deserialize it, and tried the following:

```
reader.ReadStartElement("NewDataSet");
var dataSet = (DataTable)new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataTable)).Deserialize(reader);
reader.ReadEndElement();
```

and also:

```
reader.ReadStartElement("NewDataSet");
var dataSet = (DataSet)new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataSet)).Deserialize(reader);
reader.ReadEndElement();
```

All I got was

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>     Message=There is an error in XML document (26, 14).
>     Source=System.Xml

InnerException:

> "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'> was not expected."

**How can I deserialize that thing?**

Comment: I think the issue is because you already called reader.ReadStartElement, try initializing the reader and passing it straight to the XmlSerializer

Comment: Can you please write an example code how to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Managed to solve it. Seems like when we directly read to an existing `DataSet` using its `ReadXml()` method, it just works.

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(reader);
```

Now I can reach the table as `dataSet.Tables[0]`

Comment: I serialized a DataTable into an xml string and wanted to create a unit test afterwards. With the DataSet code you provided, I can access the DataTable via the TableCollection in Tables property. Great! Have a +1 Sir.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really provide you with sample code as I don't have context to the rest of your code.

Look at the documentation to XmlSerializer.Deserialize at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize.aspx and notice the different ways to initalize it.

Your reader should be at the beginning of the stream, which it is not after you called

```
reader.ReadStartElement("NewDataSet");
```

Simply don't begin reading the XML and just pass Deserialize your reader. Even easier you can just pass it the file/memory stream directly.

Comment: It's not working either when I skip `reader.ReadStartElement("NewDataSet");`

When reader.LocalName is NewDataSet, it says "NewDataSet" is unexpected XML node...

Comment: It's really impossible to tell you what's going on without context, update your question please.